# Python library for creating movies from frames

Tags: library, video, python, image-processing

Wanted: A Python library (supporting at least Python 3.5+) that can take a sequence of (non-animated) raster images (in some format that [Pillow](http://pillow.readthedocs.io) can generate) plus timing information and create a movie (not GIF!) file — MPEG, MP4, or whatever the kids are watching these days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MoviePy](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/moviepy) can do what you need with the heavy lifting behind the scenes being done by [FFMPEG](http://ffmpeg.org/), *which it downloads and installs of first use.* The [documentation](http://zulko.github.io/moviepy/) is also very helpful.

- Support MP4 and any other FFMPEG supported output format *as well as GIFs*.
- Inputs can be:

  - Just about any FFMPEG supported input format
  - Any PIL/[Pillow](https://python-pillow.org/) supported input format as an [Image Clip](http://zulko.github.io/moviepy/getting_started/videoclips.html#imageclip)
  - [Numpy Arrays](http://zulko.github.io/moviepy/getting_started/working_with_matplotlib.html#defining-custom-animations)
  - [MatPlotLib plots](http://zulko.github.io/moviepy/getting_started/working_with_matplotlib.html#simple-matplotlib-example)
  - [Text](http://zulko.github.io/moviepy/getting_started/videoclips.html#textclip) *with [ImageMagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) installed*
  - The results of OpenCV processing
  - Vector Animations
  - 3D Animations
- It is cross platform with even a pre-configured [Docker](http://zulko.github.io/moviepy/docker.html) container available.
- Works with Python 2.7 and 3.3+

[image][image]

Of course it can do a [lot more](http://zulko.github.io/moviepy/gallery.html) besides.